# Как преобразовать дату в ISO формат?

Tags: python, python-3.x, дата, datetime

Пытаюсь преобразовать дату следующим образом, но выдает ошибку `builtins.ValueError: Invalid format string`

```py
import datetime
now = datetime.datetime.now()
print(now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d%%TH:%i:%sP'))
```

Comment: У меня ошибки нет, выводит `2022-08-26%TH:i:1661514123P`

Comment: И у меня без ошибки это же выводит

Comment: А в чем может быть дело? Версия python 3.8

Comment: Ну попробуйте по очереди исключать символы формата и найдите, на чём именно начинает ругаться. Может что-то понятнее будет. Может что-то с локалью.

Comment: @CrazyElf `strftime('%Y-%m-%d%%TH')` на этом этапе работает

Comment: И в Python 3.8 у меня тоже всё работает, правда выводит немного другой результат `2022-08-26%TH:%i:1661514512P`

Comment: Есть подозрение, что результат зависит от системы. Какая у вас система?

Comment: @andreymal win 10 32bit

Comment: А вот в Windows 10 даже в Python 3.10 действительно такая ошибка

Comment: И ошибка как раз именно из-за `%i`. Откуда вы это взяли и почему решили, что оно должно работать? В [документации](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes) такого нет

Comment: И `%s` там кстати тоже нет

Comment: @andreymal возможно, что я не так понял что-то. Формирую запрос к апи и возвращает ошибку `Value expected to be a date/time string in 'Y-m-d\\TH:i:sP'`

Comment: Ну так надо не бездумно процентики расставлять, а разобраться, что это за синтаксис такой в этой ошибке) А мой внутренний телепат подсказывает, что это [синтаксис из php](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php), а в Python-коде его примерным эквивалентом будет `%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z`

Comment: Однако с этим `%z` есть две проблемы. Во-вторых, нужно вместо `now()` использовать `now(datetime.timezone.utc)` чтобы он вообще появился (ну или подключить pytz или zoneinfo, но это уже другая история), а во-вторых, в нём, в отличие от php, нет двоеточия, так что его [придётся добавить вручную](https://gist.github.com/mattstibbs/a283f55a124d2de1b1d732daaac1f7f8)

Comment: Ну или можно ещё попробовать `now(datetime.timezone.utc).isoformat()` но в нём есть микросекунды и возможно API откажется их принимать

Comment: О, я что-то вспомнил, что мы тут в каком-то вопросе бодались уже с микросекундами в каком-то апи с год назад. Кто вообще так апи пишет, принимали бы сырой `timestamp`
 и горя бы не было.

Comment: @andreymal ответ с двоеточиями помог, можете оформить как ответ, спасибо огромное

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Помог комментарий `andreymal`.

```py
import datetime
original_timestamp = datetime.datetime.now(datetime.timezone.utc)
timestamp_string = original_timestamp.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z")
timestamp_string = "{0}:{1}".format(timestamp_string[:-2], timestamp_string[-2:])
```